# Best way to pass arguments to another page in Wordpress

Tags: customization, functions

What is the best way to pass arguments to another page in wordpress.
I did it this way :

```
<a href="get_permalinka(id_of_page).'/&i=2&j=3&k=4'">Link/a>
```

I get this arguments with $_GET['i'],$_GET['j'],$_GET['k'],problem is : this works just with default permalinks,but when I change it to some other permalink type,it does not work any more.Note - I'm passing these arguments from homepage to another page(template page).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [add_query_arg()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) to do this.

Here's a useful function if you need to get the current page URL (when get_permalink is inaccesible, like on Archives):

```
function get_current_page_url() {
  $request = esc_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

  $pageURL = (is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http').'://';
  if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$request; else $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$request;

  if (false === strpos(get_option('home'), '://www.')) $pageURL = str_replace('://www.', '://', $pageURL);
  if (false !== strpos(get_option('home'), '://www.') && false === strpos($pageURL, '://www.')) $pageURL = str_replace('://', '://www.', $pageURL);

  return $pageURL;
}
```

Comment: Ok,tnx but why $qvar = get_query_var('i'); do not work?

Comment: because you need to register that query variable to wp. see the `query_vars` filter

Comment: What do you mean "when get_permalink is inaccesible, like on Archives"... curious..

Comment: I wrote this :         add_filter('query_vars', 'p_query');

        function p_query($qvars) {
            $qvars[] = 'i';
            return $qvars;
        } and it does not work.

Comment: @t31os: I meant the permalink of the current page, not the one from the posts listed on that page; @user1147: post your entire code

Comment: It really depends what that archives.php is doing though, you're possibly "assuming" it's modified the main query object or declaring a new one(i didn't see this mentioned), it may not be doing either, it could be showing a simple list of categories for all we know..

Answer (score 1):

```
    add_filter('query_vars', 'p_query');

    function p_query($qvars) {
        $qvars[] = 'i';
        return $qvars;
    }

     <a href="<?= add_query_arg('i', '2', get_permalink(some_page_id)); ?>">Link</a>
```

and on the page I call

```
$qvar = get_query_var('i');
echo $qvar;
```

$qvar is empty!

Comment: This should of been added to the original question, unless you're answering(providing a solution) to your own question.

Comment: Well it can be a solution to his questions, as the code is correct and works as long this is done on singular type page. If not, use the get_current_page_url() function above instead of get_permalink()...

Comment: Part with get_permalink works,on other page where I call get_query_var,that thing do not work?

Comment: let's clear this thing out - You add the filter in your functions.php; The "Link" can be anywhere (ps: I suggest you use `<?php echo` instead of `<?=`); When you click the link it should take your to a page where you can access your query variable (the link and address bar should point to something like `site/page/?i=2`)

Comment: I didn't put my filter in function.php,now I put it and it works